# SlowCheetah - TeamCity - [restore] Unable to find version '2.5.15' of package 'SlowCheetah'

Tags: build, nuget, teamcity, slowcheetah

I have an issue with my TeamCity instance not retrieving version 2.5.15 of SlowCheetah from TeamCity. It restores all of my other nuget based dependencies just fine.

I added SlowCheetah to one project in my Solution via the Nuget Package Manager Console and it works fine locally. However when TeamCity tries to get the nuget package is complains with

```
[restore] Unable to find version '2.5.15' of package 'SlowCheetah'.
```

I've had a look at adding a nuget installer - https://johanleino.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/making-use-of-teamcitys-nuget-capabilities-part-2/

and this

http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx

neither of which work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update your Nuget version on TeamCity.